# Defaultdict with values defaulted to negative infinity

Tags: python, defaultdict

I want to create a default dictionary in which the default values are negative infinity. I tried doing `defaultdict(float("-inf"))` but it is not working. How do I do this?

Comment: Note that the argument to `defaultdict` should be *callable*; `defaultdict(lambda: float('-inf'))` would work, for instance. See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/5029934/3001761 (not *precisely* a duplicate, but identical underlying issue).

Comment: @jonrsharpe thats an answer not a comment :P

Comment: @JoranBeasley I was looking for a dupe, but I couldn't find a really good one...

Comment: This should be a duplicate of [Python Argument Binders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277922/python-argument-binders) but I am out of close votes today.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As the traceback **specifically tells you**:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> dct = defaultdict(float('-inf'))

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    dct = defaultdict(float('-inf'))
TypeError: first argument must be callable
```

and [per the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) (emphasis mine):

> If `default_factory` [the first argument to `defaultdict`] is not `None`, it is **called without arguments** to provide a default value for the given key, this value is inserted in the dictionary for the key, and returned.

`float('-inf')` is *not* callable. Instead, you could do e.g.:

```
dct = defaultdict(lambda: float('-inf'))
```

providing a callable [*"lambda expression"*](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions) that returns the default value. It's for the same reason that you see code with e.g. `defaultdict(int)` rather than `defaultdict(0)`:

```
>>> int()  # callable
0  # returns the desired default value
```

You would also get similar issues when e.g. trying to nest `defaultdict`s within each other (see [Python: defaultdict of defaultdict?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5029934/3001761)).

Comment: Thanks that worked. I got confused since when making the default an `int` I don't need to do that.

Comment: @accelke no, because `int` is callable and returns the default value to use; I've included this example in my answer.

Comment: thanks, this advice helped me create a dict with [0,0] as the default value: `presults=defaultdict(lambda:[0,0])`