# nesting defaultdicts in an arbitrary depth

Tags: python

I would like to nest an arbitrary number of defaultdicts like so:

```
from collections import defaultdict   
D = defaultdict( lambda:defaultdict(int) )
```

this works fine as described [earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5029934/python-defaultdict-of-defaultdict).

Now I'm looking for the way/function to do this for an arbitrary depth:
so for instance I'd like to have a function

```
def Gen_DDict( dim=3 ):
    "code I'm looking for"
```

that will return this for dim=3:

```
defaultdict( lambda : defaultdict( lambda : defaultdict(int) ) )
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
def genDDict(dim=3):
    if dim==1:
        return collections.defaultdict(int)
    else:
        return collections.defaultdict(lambda: genDDict(dim-1))
```

Output:

```
In [257]: d = genDDict(2)

In [258]: d[2][1]
Out[258]: 0
```

Comment: Perfect exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this iteratively with a for loop building from the inside outward:

```
def Gen_DDict(dim=3, inner_factory=int):
    factory = defaultdict(inner_factory)

    def get_factory(z):
        def factory_func():
            return z
        return factory_func

    for i in range(dim-1):
        factory = defaultdict(get_factory(factory))

    return factory
```