# How to safely check if a python dictionary has multiple key dictionary pairs stored recursively

Tags: python, dictionary, try-catch

If I have a dict, d and I want to check a value at `d['e']['foo']['bar']` where e and foo are dictionaries and bar gives a string what is a way to SAFELY get the value at that location? Is there anything beyond a try catch?

Comment: You could try using `collections.defaultdict()`s. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5029934/python-defaultdict-of-defaultdict

Comment: @synchronizer and then just check that the value is a "real" one or not. Thanks!

Comment: Just to be sure, I'm writing a quick program to validate what I said.

Comment: *no, I can't seem to get more than one nested defaultdict

Comment: @synchronizer yes, it *can* get more than one nested structure, but that doesn't matter, because `defaultdict` doesn't really answer the question. A `defaultdict` doesn't check that, it  creates a value *by default*

Comment: So, what exactly do you mean by "safely"? What isn't safe about a try-catch?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I think that Bren wanted a way to abstract away the process of checking whether an item already existed in the dictionary. A defaultdict works for that, though yes, it creates default values. Out of curiosity, how do you nest more than one defaultdict? I was only able to do this with one nesting before there was an error (using a lambda).

Comment: @synchronizer from [the man himself](https://twitter.com/raymondh/status/343823801278140417).

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga well I asked for beyond a try-catch, which I am sure is safe. That seems to be the best way. I thought maybe some abstraction might exist like synchronizer mentioned. I try to use try-catch as a last resort maybe I should abandon that practice.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python safe method to get value of nested dictionary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25833613/python-safe-method-to-get-value-of-nested-dictionary)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good way would be to use `reduce`.

```
d={'e':{'foo':{'bar':"final value"}}}
l=['e','foo','bar']
print reduce(lambda x,y:x.get(y),l, d)
```

You can make a `function` and pass a `list` to it.

Output:`final value`

Comment: @but if it a key-val pair is missing you get an exception. I think adding .get(y, default) would work to eliminate that. Though then I'd get a Type exception for None.get

Comment: @Bren but in any case you will have to handle such a case.....but in this method you can use variable values in list...its a generic function....i leave error handling to you....`.get` has a default value of `None`.You can have `exception` der

Comment: @Bren this will work all long chains as well as small ones

Comment: @Bren For a version that does not require `try-except` from the user, modify like this: `x.get(y) if x else None`.

Comment: @FMc .Get returns None by default :)

Comment: @vks Of course. But that adjustment eliminates the need for `try-except` if any keys (as opposed to just the last one) are missing.

Answer (score 1):

Use `get` with a default of an empty dictionary:

```
>>> d = {'e':{'foo':{'bar':0}}}
>>> print(d.get('e', {}).get('foo', {}).get('bar'))
0
>>> print(d.get('f', {}).get('doo', {}).get('car'))
None
>>> print(d.get('e', {}).get('foo', {}).get('car'))
None
>>> print(d.get('e', {}).get('doo', {}).get('bar'))
None
```

Comment: I was trying to avoid the long chains. But that would technically work.

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to use a simple helper function along these lines:

```
def dive(d, *ks):
    for k in ks:
        if isinstance(d, dict) and k in d:
            d = d[k]
        else:
            return None
    return d

examples = [
    {},
    {'e': {'foo': 12}},
    {'e': {'foo': {'bar': 999}}},
]

for i, e in enumerate(examples):
    print(i, dive(e, 'e', 'foo', 'bar'))
```

Output:

```
(0, None)
(1, None)
(2, 999)
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure keys are in this dict,you can just try this:

```
if "e" in d:
    print d["e"]
```

Or try to use [get](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) method,if key is not available then returns default value.

> Return the value for key if key is in the dictionary, else default. If
>   default is not given, it defaults to None, so that this method never
>   raises a KeyError.

```
d.get("e","default value")
```