# dictionary search & insert optimization

Tags: python

I'm experiencing serious slow downs when working with dictionaries as the dictionary grows to a few thousands keys.

I'm processing a file with ~1,000,000 lines of data, I'm constructing a graph like data structure using dictionaries

here's my bottle neck function

```
def create_edge(node_a, node_b, graph):
    if node_a not in graph.keys():
        graph[node_a] = {node_b: 1}
    elif node_b in graph[node_a].keys():
        graph[node_a][node_b] += 1
    else:
        graph[node_a][node_b] = 1
```

`create_edge` will create and edge from `node_a` to `node_b`, or add 1 to the weight of an already existing edge between them.

Since my nodes are identified by a string unique id, I'm using dictionaries for storage, assuming that search if a key exist, and insert would take O(1) on average.

If I comment out `create_edge` I can process around 20,000 records per seconds, with `create_edge` as a part of my pipeline it's about 20 records per sec.

The first 100 records takes about 500ms to process.
When the dictionary size grows to around 10,000 - Processing 100 records take about 15,000ms, every record process invokes `create_edge` about 4 times on average - So 400 calls for `create_edge` takes 15 seconds when the dictionary size is 10,000.

First, do these runtimes make sense? Seems way to much to me, correct me if I'm wrong.

Second, suggestions of optimizing the dictionary usage for better run time would be greatly appreciated.

I'm expecting the dictionary size to be at least 100,000 to complete processing for the entire 1,000,000 records.

---

Edit: Conclusions

You were right on the money, did two noob mistakes here.. :)

The `keys()` calls increase complexity dramaticly, taking it from constant time to poly time (squared) per edge insertion, replacing `if node in graph.keys()`  with `if node in graph` produces a constant process time of 100 records in ~300ms.

Second mistake was virtualenv config which led me to believe im using python3 while I was actualy using python2.

python3 do optimizes the keys() code into a constant time search, which is good for run time but less for proper code style.

### Thanks a lot for your assistance.

---

I performed a run time comparison after removing the `keys()` calls.

```
# graph = {}
python version: 3.6.3
start time 11:44:56
Number of records: 1029493
graph created, 1231630 nodes
end time 11:50:35
total ~05:39

# graph = defaultdict(lambda : defaultdict(int))
python version: 3.6.3
start time 11:54:52
Number of records: 1029493
graph created, 1231630 nodes
end time  12:00:34
total ~05:42

# graph = {}
python version: 2.7.10
start time 12:03:25
Number of records: 1029493
graph created, 1231630 nodes
end time 12:09:40
total ~06:15
```

Comment: What Python version is this?

Comment: Are you on Python 2, per chance?

Comment: Because `.keys()` gets a **List** of the keys, not a dictionary. So inside `create_edge` you are doing two `O(n)` operations to search from the entire dictionary converted into a list, twice. You will want to do `if node_a in graph`, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1602934/check-if-a-given-key-already-exists-in-a-dictionary). *Note* as mentioned in the comments below this only applies when using Python 2, not 3.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek that's what I suspect, since it a a famous Python anti-pattern, but in Python 3, it returns a *view* of the keys with O(1) membership testing.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek It should be noted that in `python3` `dict.keys()` returns an iterator

Comment: have you thought about using https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/? They have a very good graph object that is pretty fast for construction.

Comment: Do not use `if node_a not in graph.keys():` but `if node_a not in graph:`

Comment: @AlanSTACK no, it does *not* return an iterator, although, the `dict_keys` object is iterable. Don't believe me? Try `next({}.keys())`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Membership testing might be `O(1)`, but instantiation might be `O(n)`

Comment: @AlanSTACK It isn't.  Calling `some_dict.keys()` is constant time. Essentially, it's an object that wraps the underlying hash-map that acts like a set.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga It *is* O(n). Can't be O(1) and not be O(n).

Comment: @StefanPochmann ok ok, but it *is* O(1), and the time to create the view object doesn't depend on the size of the dict.

Comment: @StefanPochmann: In Python-3.x it is *O(1)*, since `.keys()` acts as a Proxy object. Both construction of `.keys()` and membercheck is in *O(1)*.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Not sure why you're telling me that. I never disagreed with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When testing for the existence of a key in a `dict`, just use `key in d`, rather than `key in d.keys()`.  Extracting the keys to test for membership negates the benefit of using a `dict` in the first place.

Try the following:

```
def create_edge(node_a, node_b, graph):
    if node_a not in graph:
        graph[node_a] = {node_b: 1}
    elif node_b in graph[node_a]:
        graph[node_a][node_b] += 1
    else:
        graph[node_a][node_b] = 1
```

Notice that `keys()` isn't called at all.  This should be a lot faster than what you're doing now.

Note that in Python 2 the `keys()` check will be much slower than in Python 3, since in Python 2 `keys()` creates a list of the entire set of keys.  It works differently in Python 3, but even in Python 3 checking for membership directly, without using `keys()`, will be faster.

Comment: good explanation about the keys() part but without defaultdict/Counter it'll still be slow.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre A `defaultdict` will be faster, but the biggest problem in the code was that it was using `keys()`, especially if OP was using Python 2.  Using a `defaultdict` might at best triple the speed by avoiding redundant key checks, but it does have the advantage that it eliminates the possibility of calling `keys()` by mistake.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Please show your benchmark supporting that statement.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Mine disagrees, defaultdict+Counter taking almost twice as long as the OP's (fixed) way: https://ideone.com/DvufOu

Comment: @StefanPochmann Interesting.  I guess `defaultdict` is less efficient than I gave it credit for.

Comment: @TomKarzes Hmm, I just realized my test wasn't quite what it should be, since I used unique edges only. Here's a version where I have each edge ten times, and there the defaultdict[defaultdict[int]] wins (but defaultdict[Counter] is still the loser): https://ideone.com/ckF0X5

Comment: @StefanPochmann Thank you for the tests! This confirms defaultdict(int) is the fastest approach in some cases and a big plus the lower amount of code :)

Comment: @StefanPochmann hashing of the keys makes a difference here. With string keys, the hashing is more expensive, so `defaultdict` wins.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre In my latter test, `defaultdict` already won, so I guess you're talking about my former test? I changed that to use string keys, and `dict` still won: https://ideone.com/YLm53K Can you please share your test code?

Comment: @TomKarzes I'd btw replace "This should be a bit faster" with "This should be a lot faster".

Answer (score 3):

Can't u just use a defaultdict with defaultdict(int) as seen here: [Python: defaultdict of defaultdict?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5029934/python-defaultdict-of-defaultdict)

```
from collections import defaultdict

graph = defaultdict(lambda : defaultdict(int))

graph['a']['b'] += 1
graph['a']['b'] += 1
graph['a']['c'] += 1

graph
```

Returns:

```
defaultdict(<function __main__.<lambda>>,
            {'a': defaultdict(int, {'b': 2, 'c': 1})})
# equal to: {'a': {'b': 2, 'c': 1}}
```

Comment: Is that actually faster than the OP's (after fixing their `.keys()` mistake, of course). Can you share your benchmark results?

Comment: Since I’m not sitting on the data set, I thought OP could do it.

Comment: @StefanPochmann It will likely be much faster.  Context switching (calling `create_edge`) is pretty expensive.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh I don't see a big difference, have a look at the times at the bottom: https://ideone.com/SajEsd. And that's with actually adding edges with that function. If I do it inline, the OP's way is significantly *faster* in my test: https://ideone.com/DvufOu

Comment: will definitly try using lambdas and defaultdict and post results, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I tried several methods and this is one that seems to work. This method use a counter to count all occurances first and then build the dictionary. Thanks @Stefan Pochmann to provide benchmark scripts. One I used is from  [ideone.com/ckF0X5](https://ideone.com/ckF0X5)

I am using Python 3.6 and the result is tested on my computer.

```
from timeit import timeit
from collections import defaultdict, Counter
from random import shuffle
from itertools import product

def f():   # OP's method modified with Tom Karzes' answer above.
    d = {}
    for i, j in edges:
        if i not in d:
            d[i] = {j: 1}
        elif j in d[i]:
            d[i][j] += 1
        else:
            d[i][j] = 1

def count_first(): 
    d = dict()
    for (v, w), c in Counter(edges).items():
        if v not in d:
            d[v] = {w: c}
        else:
            d[v][w] = c
    # Alternatively, (Thanks to Jean-François Fabre to point it out.)
    # d = defaultdict(lambda : defaultdict(int)) 
    # for (v, w), c in Counter(edges).items(): 
    #     d[v][w] = c

edges = list(product(range(300), repeat=2)) * 10
shuffle(edges)

# %timeit f()
270 ms ± 23.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
# %timeit count_first()
180 ms ± 15.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Declaimer: The results of `count_first()` that I get from the ideone.com is, however, slower than the OP's answer, `f()` here.

Stefan Pochmann did a benchmark experiment to compare different approaches in both Python 2 and 3. His result in Python 2 can be found [here](https://ideone.com/PFK7yX). For Python 3, check [this](https://ideone.com/nCNaxp). Credits to him and thanks his code review.

Comment: I get slightly more speed with `d = defaultdict(lambda : defaultdict(int))
    for v, c in Counter(edges).items():
        d[v[0]][v[1]] = c`

Comment: Interesting idea, this pre-counting. Why not `c = Counter(edges)`, though? And yes, for my benchmarks I used Python 2 because that's what the OP was using (Ideone supports Python 3 as well). I just ran 1-dimensional tests with more methods. In Python 2, `defaultdict` won, followed by `dict`, and `Counter` was a lot slower: https://ideone.com/PFK7yX. In Python 3, the picture is similar, except giving the data to the `Counter` constructor went from very slow to by far fastest: https://ideone.com/nCNaxp. I wonder why...

Comment: Ah, right. That part of `Counter` got faster because it got implemented in C.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre They seem to be roughly the same speed. (sharing the same mean and standard deviation. from my machine) But the code is cleaner!

Comment: @StefanPochmann Thanks for the heads-up and benchmark experiments. Updated the code.

Comment: Could also do `for (v, w), c in ...`