# Create a dict if its not already created and then append to it

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

I have a list of files in which I need to select few lines which has CommonChar in them and work on creating a dictionary. 
The lines in a file which I am interested in look like these:

```
CommonChar uniqueName field value 

CommonChar uniqueName field1 value1

CommonChar uniqueName1 field value

CommonChar uniqueName1 field1 value1
```

So with this I would want a final dictionary which will store internal dictionaries named on uniqueName and key value pairs as (field: value, field1:value1)

This way I will have a main dict with internal dict based on uniqueName and key value pairs.

Final output should look like this:

```
mainDic={'uniqueName': {'field':'value', 'field1':value1, 'field2':value2},
          'uniqueName1':{'field':'value', 'field1':value1, 'field2':value2} }
```

Comment: `'Apple' in mainDict`...`mainDict['Apple']={}`......`mainDict['Apple']['American']=33`

Comment: people have mentioned membership checks, but setdefault is really the way to go here.

Comment: I have updated my question to make it more clear ....

Answer (score 0):

Check out defaultdict! Import with `from collections import defaultdict`. If you start with `mainDict = defaultdict(dict)` it will automatically create the dictionary if you try to assign a key. `mainDict['Apple']['American'] = '16'` will work like magic.

If you need to increment new keys in the sub dictionaries, [you can also put a defaultdict in a defaultdict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5029934/python-defaultdict-of-defaultdict)

documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict

Comment: If you want to use `dict` and manually check, it looks like there are plenty of threads on that (e.g. the possible duplicates).

Answer (score 0):

'Apple' and 'Grapes' can't be created as dictionaries since they are strings. I'm assuming you have a flow in your program that goes something 
like this:

1. create a dictionary containing information about apples
2. assign that dictionary to the variable apple
3. check if this just created dictionary is already in mainDict
4. if not, add it to the values of mainDict under the key 'Apple'

   ```
   mainDict= {'Grapes':{'Arabian':'25','Indian':'20'} }
   apple = {'American':'16', 'Mexican':10, 'Chinese':5}

   if apple not in mainDict.values():
       mainDict['Apple'] = apple

   mainDict
   ```

output:

```
{'Apple': {'American': '16', 'Chinese': 5, 'Mexican': 10},
 'Grapes': {'Arabian': '25', 'Indian': '20'}}
```

The problem I think you have, is that there's no general way to get the name 
of an object as a string. Dicts don't have a **name** attribute. Refer to these answers: [How can I get the name of an object in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1538342/how-can-i-get-the-name-of-an-object-in-python)