# dict and list in Python

Tags: python

This is my data:

```
2018-06-19 136768197 e230702d
2018-06-19 136768197 f14c4f07
2018-06-15 1157040118 a527b130
2018-06-15 1157040118 f05a746f
```

As output I need the following dict

```
{
  '2018-06-19': {
    '136768197': ['e230702d', 'f14c4f07']
  },
  '2018-06-15': {
    '1157040118': ['a527b130', 'f05a746f']
  }
}
```

My attempt to resolve the problem:

```
d = defaultdict(list)
c = dict()
with open("c:/Python/hitId.txt") as f:    
    for line in f:
        key, s, h = line.split()
        d[s].append(h)
        c[key] = d
```

But the output contains duplicated data (formatted to highlight issue):

```
{'2018-06-15': {'1157040118': ['a527b130', 'f05a746f'],'136768197': ['e230702d', 'f14c4f07']}),
 '2018-06-19': {'1157040118': ['a527b130', 'f05a746f'],'136768197': ['e230702d', 'f14c4f07']})}
```

Comment: What is the problem? Add all of the relevant code.

Comment: This isn't even a valid Python dictionary.

Comment: Is the data inside a file? How will you input that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: `code 
c = defaultdict (dict) 
for row in rows: 
    key, s, h = row [0], row [1], row [2] 
    d[s].append (h) 
    c [key] [s] = d [s] `

Comment: You assign the same **global variable** - `d` - for all keys of `c`. So you have the same value for all keys. Also, by assigning `c[key]` in a loop, you rewrite previous value for the key.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want a default dict of default dicts as answered in [Python: defaultdict of defaultdict?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5029934/python-defaultdict-of-defaultdict) ; I debated whether this should be a duplicate question (and if someone wants to say it is, that's fine), but basically I think something like:

```
x = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(list))
with open("c:/Python/hitId.txt") as f:    
    for line in f:
        key, s, h = line.split()
        x[key][s].append(h)
```

should get you what you're looking for (a little extra work required to convert to a raw dict).  If you want to ultimately just print it out

```
  import json
  print(json.dumps(x))
```

should do it