# Build a dict and populate it in a for loop

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I'm trying to build a dictionary that should contain data about a coin, date and its close price on the given date.

The data I'm looping through, which I am using as the base out of which I want to build my dict, look like this (it's a Python list):

```
[('2018-08-31', 'BSV', 0.0), ('2018-08-31', 'EOS', 6.4050002), ('2018-08-31', 'ETC', 12.7299995), ('2018-08-31', 'BNB', 10.96), ('2018-08-31', 'LTC', 62.1300011), ('2018-08-31', 'XMR', 116.1399994), ('2018-08-31', 'BTT', 0.0), ('2018-08-31', 'BCH', 542.4199829), ('2018-08-31', 'ADA', 0.1039), ('2018-08-31', 'DASH', 194.25), ('2018-08-31', 'BTC', 7014.6000977), ('2018-08-31', 'ZEC', 149.6300049), ('2018-08-31', 'XLM', 0.2216), ('2018-08-31', 'XRP', 0.335), ('2018-08-31', 'QTUM', 4.7399998), ('2018-08-31', 'NEO', 20.1100006), ('2018-08-31', 'ETH', 281.6300049), ('2018-08-31', 'TRX', 0.02532), ('2018-09-01', 'BSV', 0.0), ('2018-09-01', 'EOS', 6.6620002), ('2018-09-01', 'ETC', 13.1899996), ('2018-09-01', 'BNB', 11.4499998), ('2018-09-01', 'LTC', 66.5), ('2018-09-01', 'XMR', 121.0299988), ('2018-09-01', 'BTT', 0.0), ('2018-09-01', 'BCH', 618.8699951), ('2018-09-01', 'ADA', 0.1098)]
```

It's a list of tuples and each tuple has this value in it: `(date, coin, close_price)`.

My expected JSON at the end should look like this:

```
{
    "coins": [{
        "BTC": [{
            "2018-08-31": 7014.6000977
        }, {
            "2018-09-01": 7197.3999023
        }],
        "EOS": [{
            "2018-08-31": 6.4050002
        }, {
            "2018-09-01": 6.6620002
        }]
    }]
}
```

My current code to build such a JSON looks like this:

```
prices_json = {"coins": []}
for date, _coin, close_price in prices: #prices is the above-mentioned list of tuples
    if date:
        prices_json["coins"].append(
            {
                f"{_coin}": []
            }
        )
        prices_json["coins"][0][f"{_coin}"].append(
            {
                f"{date}": f"{close_price}"
            }
        )
```

The reason I want to build a JSON like this from the provided list of tuples is, that I want to access the close_price data in this way:

```py
my_json_with_prices[f"{coin}"][f"{date}"]
```

This should result in the close price number, for example `6.4050002`

The values of `f"{coin}"` and `"f{date}"` will be provided in a for loop later on in the script.

If you have any other idea how to access the `close_price` values from the list of tuples based on the `date` and the `coin`, I am open to all of the suggestions.

Comment: You seem to be asking about how to build a dictionary, not about producing JSON. I have edited accordingly, but left in the JSON terminology in a couple of places. Please review.

Comment: `f"{_coin}"` is a really roundabout way to say `str(_coin)`, or just `_coin` if you know it's already a string.

Comment: Why would you store the endprices as list of dicts with one date->value each? If you only have one closing value per date per coin a dict of date->value  should suffice. If you have more then 1 closing value, you're a time traveler...

Comment: The root dict with just `"coins"` as its sole key seems completely redundant here.

Comment: @tripleee I agree

Comment: Why do you want the innermost information to be a list of dictionaries with a single key in each? Assuming the dates will always be unique (because how would you otherwise interpret the data? A coin can't possibly have two correct values at a given time) it makes sense for the per-coin information to be just a dictionary. (I guess @Patrick was trying to say something similar.)

Comment: You are both right - for every single coin and every single day there is only 1 price.
@tripleee What do you mean exactly with the 'per-coin information to be just a dictionary'?

Comment: As mentioned in my question, if someone has a better approach/structure to achieve my described goal, please share it - I'm open to all of the suggestions. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating unnecessary nesting inside the dictionary. You may represent the data as follows,

```
    prices_json = {
        currency1 : {
            date1 : price1,
            date2 : price2
        }
        
        currency2 : {
            date1 : price1,
            date2 : price2
        }
    }
```

Given the list of the tuples,

```
prices = [('2018-08-31', 'BSV', 0.0), ('2018-08-31', 'EOS', 6.4050002), ('2018-08-31', 'ETC', 12.7299995), ('2018-08-31', 'BNB', 10.96), ('2018-08-31', 'LTC', 62.1300011), ('2018-08-31', 'XMR', 116.1399994), ('2018-08-31', 'BTT', 0.0), ('2018-08-31', 'BCH', 542.4199829), ('2018-08-31', 'ADA', 0.1039), ('2018-08-31', 'DASH', 194.25), ('2018-08-31', 'BTC', 7014.6000977), ('2018-08-31', 'ZEC', 149.6300049), ('2018-08-31', 'XLM', 0.2216), ('2018-08-31', 'XRP', 0.335), ('2018-08-31', 'QTUM', 4.7399998), ('2018-08-31', 'NEO', 20.1100006), ('2018-08-31', 'ETH', 281.6300049), ('2018-08-31', 'TRX', 0.02532), ('2018-09-01', 'BSV', 0.0), ('2018-09-01', 'EOS', 6.6620002), ('2018-09-01', 'ETC', 13.1899996), ('2018-09-01', 'BNB', 11.4499998), ('2018-09-01', 'LTC', 66.5), ('2018-09-01', 'XMR', 121.0299988), ('2018-09-01', 'BTT', 0.0), ('2018-09-01', 'BCH', 618.8699951), ('2018-09-01', 'ADA', 0.1098)
```

The code to load it into the `prices_json` may look something like this,

```
prices_json = {}

for date, currency, price in prices:
  
    prices_json[currency] = prices_json.get(currency, {})
    prices_json[currency][date] = price
```

After running the code you would be able to fetch the price of a specific currency for a given date in this way,

```
prices_json[currency][date]
```

Answer (score 0):

The structure you are building has several levels of nesting. Let's think about them inside out.

Each coin's data is a mapping from date to value. It makes sense for this to be a single `dict` rather than a list of singleton dictionaries. To add a new mapping, just set `coindict[date] = value`

The structure above this is a dictionary of coin names, which are strings, with a `coindict` as described above as the value of each.

Python's `defaultdict` provides a good way to avoid having to go through

```py
if key not in dic:
    dic[key] = dict()
# now safe to add something to dic[key]
```

So with that, let's traverse your input structure.

```py
from collections import defaultdict

# see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5029934/defaultdict-of-defaultdict
close_price = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(dict))

for date, coin, price in prices:
    close_price[coin][date] = price
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/Zulvwe

Now, `close_price[coin][date]` produces the close value of `coin` on `date`, assuming of course that `date` exists as a key in `close_price[coin]`. To loop over the available dates for a particular coin, simply `for date in close_price[coin]:`

If you want to put `close_price` inside another dictionary, that's easy, too, but seems redundant:

```py
unnecessary = {"coins": [close_price] }
```

If you want to save this as JSON, try

```py
import json
with open('coins.json', 'w') as jfile:
    json.dump(unnecessary, jfile)
```

Answer (score 0):

use pandas -

```
import pandas as pd
df  = pd.DataFrame(l1,columns= ['date','coin', 'value'])
temp_list = df.groupby('coin',as_index=False).agg(list).to_dict(orient='records')
result = {
    item['coin']: (dict(zip(item['date'], item['value'])))
    for item in temp_list
}
result = {'coins': result}
print(result)
```

output -

```
{'coins': {'ADA': {'2018-08-31': 0.1039, '2018-09-01': 0.1098},
  'BCH': {'2018-08-31': 542.4199829, '2018-09-01': 618.8699951},
  'BNB': {'2018-08-31': 10.96, '2018-09-01': 11.4499998},
  'BSV': {'2018-08-31': 0.0, '2018-09-01': 0.0},
  'BTC': {'2018-08-31': 7014.6000977},
  'BTT': {'2018-08-31': 0.0, '2018-09-01': 0.0},
  'DASH': {'2018-08-31': 194.25},
  'EOS': {'2018-08-31': 6.4050002, '2018-09-01': 6.6620002},
  'ETC': {'2018-08-31': 12.7299995, '2018-09-01': 13.1899996},
  'ETH': {'2018-08-31': 281.6300049},
  'LTC': {'2018-08-31': 62.1300011, '2018-09-01': 66.5},
  'NEO': {'2018-08-31': 20.1100006},
  'QTUM': {'2018-08-31': 4.7399998},
  'TRX': {'2018-08-31': 0.02532},
  'XLM': {'2018-08-31': 0.2216},
  'XMR': {'2018-08-31': 116.1399994, '2018-09-01': 121.0299988},
  'XRP': {'2018-08-31': 0.335},
  'ZEC': {'2018-08-31': 149.6300049}}}
```

Comment: Pandas is severe overkill for this simple task. The code is much too dense for a beginner question.

Comment: Yup. It’s just another way to solve the issue. Plus, you can do more manipulation very easily, if required :)

Comment: Thank you @Nk03 but I have used the code from nilTheDev :)

Answer (score 0):

Your question says:

> The reason I want to build a JSON like this from the provided list of
> tuples is, that I want to access the close_price data in this way:
>
> ```
> my_json_with_prices[f"{coin}"][f"{date}"]
> ```

You don't need a JSON structure for that. JSON is an *interchange* format. Python's native dicts will do exactly what you want. Even this:

```
 my_json_with_prices[f"{coin}"][f"{date}"]
```

is overcomplicated. The Python equivalent is

```
 python_equivalent[coin][date]
```

You can build a structure that does this as follows:

```
# Start with the data
data = [('2018-08-31', 'BSV', 0.0), ('2018-08-31', 'EOS', 6.4050002), ('2018-08-31', 'ETC', 12.7299995), ('2018-08-31', 'BNB', 10.96), ('2018-08-31', 'LTC', 62.1300011), ('2018-08-31', 'XMR', 116.1399994), ('2018-08-31', 'BTT', 0.0), ('2018-08-31', 'BCH', 542.4199829), ('2018-08-31', 'ADA', 0.1039), ('2018-08-31', 'DASH', 194.25), ('2018-08-31', 'BTC', 7014.6000977), ('2018-08-31', 'ZEC', 149.6300049), ('2018-08-31', 'XLM', 0.2216), ('2018-08-31', 'XRP', 0.335), ('2018-08-31', 'QTUM', 4.7399998), ('2018-08-31', 'NEO', 20.1100006), ('2018-08-31', 'ETH', 281.6300049), ('2018-08-31', 'TRX', 0.02532), ('2018-09-01', 'BSV', 0.0), ('2018-09-01', 'EOS', 6.6620002), ('2018-09-01', 'ETC', 13.1899996), ('2018-09-01', 'BNB', 11.4499998), ('2018-09-01', 'LTC', 66.5), ('2018-09-01', 'XMR', 121.0299988), ('2018-09-01', 'BTT', 0.0), ('2018-09-01', 'BCH', 618.8699951), ('2018-09-01', 'ADA', 0.1098

# Get the coins
coins = set(d[1] for d in data)

# Build an empty lookup table for each coin
lookup = {}
for c in coins:
    lookup[c] = {}

# Now populate it
for date, c, price in data:
    lookup[c][date] = price
```

(That can be done in fewer steps.) This will allow you do do

```
required_value = lookup[coin][date]
```

If you really want a JSON structure for this, though I can't imagine why unless you are passing it to some other program, then

```
my_json_with_prices = json.dumps(lookup)
```

Comment: Thank you @BoarGules - I didn't end up using your code but thank you again for your time and effort :)