# Issues building nested dictionary with python lists

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm using the following method to build a nested dictionary using 2 python lists:

```
lvl1 = ['a', 'b']
lvl2 = ['apples','bananas']
results = defaultdict(dict)
for one in lvl1:
    for two in lvl2:
        results[one][two] = 0
```

I'm having issues using the same method with 3 python lists (an additional layer). Any ideas?

```
lvl1 = ['a', 'b']
lvl2 = ['apples','bananas']
lvl3 = ['size','depth']
results = defaultdict(dict)

# ERRORS OUT
for one in lvl1:
    for two in lvl2:
        for three in lvl3:
            results[one][two][three] = 0

Desired Output:
{'a':{'apples':{'size':0, 'depth':0}, 'bananas':{'size':0, 'depth':0}},
 'b':{'apples':{'size':0, 'depth':0}, 'bananas':{'size':0, 'depth':0}}}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [defaultdict of defaultdict?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5029934/defaultdict-of-defaultdict)

Comment: It is better to  use zip.

Comment: and or check out `setdefault()` method of a regular dictionary. `results.setdefault(one, {}).setdefault(two, {})[three] = 0`

Comment: @toyotaSupra I figured out a solution, but interested in how to use zip here if it's cleaner?

Comment: @toyotaSupra I'm also interested in how `zip()` would be a better option. Perhaps you meant `itertools.product()` to generate the keys rather than nested `for` loops. How would that address the root issue of defaultdict of defaultdict?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use lambda so that it can create a new **defaultdict(dict)** whenever a new key is accessed in **results**.

```
results = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(dict))
```

Comment: Do you disagree that this question is a duplicate of [defaultdict of defaultdict?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5029934/defaultdict-of-defaultdict)?

Answer (score 1):

When you use the defaultdic with 2 layers you are getting `results[one]` which because it is a defaultdict and not a dict creates an empty dict for you and returns it, you then assign to `results[one][two]`

In the 3 layer example `results[one]` is a regular empty dict and you are now getting `results[one][two]` and not assigning to it

you could create a nested default dict:

```
results = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(dict))
```

and that would work with 3 layers...
but not with 4...

plus, it's not very pretty

**edit:**

you cold create a recursive defaultdict:

```
def recursive_defaultdict():
   return defaultdict(recursive_defaultdict)

results = recursive_defaultdict()
results['I']['am']['a']['little']['teapot'] = 'short and stout'
```

**edit end**

Another approach would be to use a regular dictionary with setdefault

```
lvl1 = ['a', 'b']
lvl2 = ['apples','bananas']
lvl3 = ['size','depth']
results = {}

for one in lvl1:
    for two in lvl2:
        for three in lvl3:
            results.setdefault(one, {}).setdefault(two, {})[three] = 0
```

but some would argue that the simplest approach is the most readable and elegant

```
lvl1 = ['a', 'b']
lvl2 = ['apples','bananas']
lvl3 = ['size','depth']
results = {}

for one in lvl1:
    results[one] = {}
    for two in lvl2:
        results[one][two] = {}
        for three in lvl3:
            results[one][two][three] = 0
```

**edit 2**

Yet another possible approach would be to use comprehensions:

```
results = {
    one: {
        two: {
            three: 0
            for three in lvl3
        }
        for two in lvl2
    }
    for one in lvl1
}
```

Comment: Do you disagree that this question is a duplicate of [defaultdict of defaultdict?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5029934/defaultdict-of-defaultdict)?

Comment: @JonSG Yes, I think the other question assumes the solution is a nested defaultdict, where this one is looking to solve a practical problem. I think that is apparent in my answer that explores other possible methods